# How can I add more items to an EmbeddedDocument with MongoEngine?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I'm trying to check if there is already an item with the current date and if not I will add it. the code below is not prompting any errors but it's not saving anything to MongoDB

```
if len(site.DaylyLog) != 0:
    print len(site.DaylyLog)
    print site.DaylyLog[-1]
    current_date_daylylog = site.DaylyLog[-1]['aggregate_date']
else:
    current_date_daylylog = ''

if current_date_daylylog == datetime.date.today():
    #update document
    print current_date_daylylog
    print "calculating averages"

    site.DaylyLog[-1].average_response_time = (site.DaylyLog[-1].average_response_time+record_uptime.response_time)/2
    site.DaylyLog[-1].average_uptime = (site.DaylyLog[-1].average_uptime+100)/2

    site.save()
else:
    print current_date_daylylog
    print "adding new uptime"

    print site.url
    aggregate_uptime = AggregatedUptime()
    aggregate_uptime.average_response_time = record_uptime.response_time
    aggregate_uptime.average_uptime = 100
    aggregate_uptime.total_downtime = 0
    aggregate_uptime.aggregate_date = datetime.date.today()

    print aggregate_uptime.aggregate_date
    print aggregate_uptime.average_response_time

    site.DaylyLog.append(aggregate_uptime)
    site.save()

    print site.DaylyLog[-1].aggregate_date
```

Comment: can you post your models too?

Comment: Thanks a lot. As it happens the problem was that i've changed the reference in the model and forgot to change the view. :-)

Comment: do you run this multi-threaded? is there a concern that more than one thread will try to update the same document?

Comment: It's not the case. I have other things controlling that so it won't happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment above. The code I've posted was ok, but it was refencing something that i've changed in the model. It was just a newbie problem. :-)

The old model was

```
class Checkr(Document):
 name = StringField()
 slug = SlugField()
 url = URLField()
 frequency = IntField()
 owner = IntField()
 start_date = DateTimeField()
 end_date = DateTimeField()
 current_response_time = FloatField()
 current_response_code = IntField()
 hourly_log = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(AggregatedUptime))
 dayly_log = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(AggregatedUptime))
 weekly_log = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(AggregatedUptime))
```

When it should be

```
class Checkr(Document):
 name = StringField()
 slug = SlugField()
 url = URLField()
 frequency = IntField()
 owner = IntField()
 start_date = DateTimeField()
 end_date = DateTimeField()
 current_response_time = FloatField()
 current_response_code = IntField()
 HourlyLog = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(AggregatedUptime))
 DaylyLog = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(AggregatedUptime))
 WeeklyLog = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(AggregatedUptime))
```